# MySQL Select all from Table 1 where Foreign key not exists or is not equal to specified key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Hello I can't figure out how to write this select statement.
I have the following schema:
table 1 1:n table 2 n:1 table 3
So I got a n:m between table 1 and 3
what I want to do now is get all entries in table 1 that either don't have an relation to table 3 via table 2 or if there exists a relation I want only those not matching one specific table 3 primary key.
Or in other words if table 1 is products and table 3 is orders, I want to get out all products not already placed in the specific order I'm giving into the select.
I already tried a vaiety of select commands but none of them were working properly, hardest thing for me is the 'not equals orders_id' part so far I only got an empty table as a result.
[image]
I did a small paint drawing so you can understand better what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from product_orders po
    where po.product_id = o.product_id and po.order_id = ?
)
```

The question mark represents the id of the order that you give as a parameter to the query.

I doubt that you need table `orders` to generate the result you want - unless you are identifying the order by some other column than its primary key. If so, that would be:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from product_orders po
    inner join orders o on o.order_id = po.order_id
    where po.product_id = o.product_id and o.<somecol> = ?
)
```